# Where do I show info about Memory on App Inisghts Profiler?

Tags: .net, azure, memory-management, azure-application-insights, profiler

I've set the Profiler to hit when Memory is over some threashold.

I got a Hit right now, but when I expand the *Slowest wall clock time*, it shows to me only the ms in CPU which take long time.

No info about which resource are filling the memory. Where do I enable and see the informations about Memory?

Also try to download the .diagsession file, but I can only see CPU %:

[image]

Comment: Have you deployed your App to Azure App Service ?

Comment: You can see the Memory Info by clicking on  [Application dashboard](https://i.imgur.com/fkXZecc.png) or from [Metrics](https://i.imgur.com/9Vtfzxl.png) under monitoring.

Comment: @Harshitha but I need, during profiling, which part of application use which memory, not the general usage.

Comment: Ok..will check and let you know

Comment: You want to check the memory details locally or in Azure Application Insights?

Comment: @Harshitha on the Profiler within Azure Application Insights...

Comment: Ok..Iam able to see the memory usage in Performance => Profiler => profile now.Enable the cpu and memory in triggers section.

Comment: @Harshitha what I miss is to check the Memory info, not trigger The Profiler. That's fancy...

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? No need to trigger the profiler.profiler gets started based on the applied Memory [Percentage](https://i.imgur.com/3S2v7PO.png)

Comment: click on the `Memory` under `Triggered By` [session](https://i.imgur.com/xsREOrc.png)You can clearly see the Events which are taking more memory..

Comment: Memory % is not shown near events,just the event details are shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where do I show info about Memory on App Inisghts Profiler?

We have an option in `Application Insights` => `Performance` => `Profiler`

- By setting the triggers, If the CPU or Memory goes above the certain threshold (which we have set in the Trigger), the service will trigger the Profiler to start.
- Here I have set the `Memory Threshold (%)` to `80`.

[image]

- The profiler gets started automatically when the CPU or memory % gets to a certain point.
- If you want to profile and know the info manually, you can click `Profile now`.
- I have run the profiler manually, you can see the details of Profile now along with CPU and Memory.

[image]

Refer MSDoc [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/profiler/profiler-overview) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/profiler/profiler) for more details.

Even MS Doc says, if we set **Memory trigger** it

> Starts Profiler when memory usage is above 80 percent.

> No info about which resource are filling the memory.

To know more details about the memory usage, click on the `Memory` under `Triggered By` session.

- You can clearly see the Events which are taking more memory.

[image]

Also refer [Configure Application Insights Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/profiler/profiler-settings) for more details.

Comment: But thats CPU time, not Memory allocation... isn't it?

Comment: The session is for memory threshold..but it is not showing memory % anywhere apart from the profile now session row.

Comment: So with the "native" profiler I can't get the info about Memory when a threshold is reached, correct? Only CPU loads?

Comment: Yes,this is what I have observed after checking all the events and logs.